# password encryption in django when importing users to USER model

Tags: python, django, encryption, sqlite, passwords

I am trying to build an Api with an old database, which i am trying to move in USER model at Django.

I configured table with Users for django USER model, however there is one problem. The passwords in old database are not encrypted, what means I can not log in with django.

Any ideas how to solve this? Is there a way to encrypt the column of passwords or I can pass this in django? Any help would be very welcomed. Thank you.

I am using sqlite3

Comment: Can't you call set_password for every user? see here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.set_password

Comment: The problem is, I already have users in database... For new users this would not be problem, because django encrypts the passwords, I am just thinking how to encrypt passwords for old users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already have a database with the user data imported, you should loop through the records and hash the passwords:

```
for user in User.objects.all():
    user.set_password(user.password)
    user.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the *security hazzard*, I guess your only option is to call [set_password](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.set_password) for users and update the password accordingly